# Why would the Serializable targetId in PermissionEvaluator be null in some cases and not others?

Tags: spring, spring-security

We are implementing `PermissionEvaluator` as follows and it throws a `NullPointerException` (commented with "NPE HERE"):

```
public class MethodsPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication,
                                 Object targetDomainObject,
                                 Object permission) {
        Object principle = authentication.getPrincipal();
        if (!(principle instanceof UserDetailsAdapter)) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication,
                                 Serializable targetId,
                                 String targetType,
                                 Object permission) {

        Object principle = authentication.getPrincipal();
        if (!(principle instanceof UserDetailsAdapter)) {
            return false;
        }
        Account account = ((UserDetailsAdapter)principle).getAccount();
       // dashboard_get permission: ensure user is manager and their company ID is the same.
       if ("dashboard_get".equals(permission)) {
           if (account instanceof Manager) {
               Company company = ((Manager)account).getCompany();
               if (company != null && company.getId().intValue() == ((Integer)targetId).intValue()) { //<-- NPE HERE
                  return true;
               }
            }
       }
      //...redacted other checks, logging
}
```

The stack trace produced showing line 54:

```
Mar 26, 2015 8:04:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.company.web.security.MethodsPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission(MethodsPermissionEvaluator.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot.hasPermission(SecurityExpressionRoot.java:140)
```

After looking at this, it appears that the targetId is null.  However, the original author of this code is able to run this code without issue.  I tried doing a diff against our repos, but did not find anything meaningful.  I also searched SO and google, but didn't turn up much info.

**Where is the Serializable targetId persisted?  Why would it be null in some cases and not others?**

Thinking that it may be how I am implementing UserDetails, here are the relevant pieces.  They are based on the implementation in Spring in Practice by Wheeler and White.

I am implementing UserDetails as follows:

```
public class UserDetailsAdapter implements UserDetails {

    public UserDetailsAdapter(Account account) {
       this.account = account;
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
       return account;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
       return account.getId();
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
       return account.getFirstName();
    }

    public String getLastName() {
       return account.getLastName();
    }

    public String getEmail() {
       return account.getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
       return account.getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
       return account.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
       return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
       return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
       return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
       return account.isEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
       Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
       for (Role role : account.getRoles()) {
         authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
       }
       return authorities;
    }

    private Account account;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2251948358105443813L;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserDetailsAdapter [account=" + account + ", firstName=" +
        account.getFirstName() + ", lastName=" + account.getLastName() + "]";
    }

}
```

And the Impl:

```
@Service("myUserDetailsService") // need a specific instance for Remember Me functionality
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
           throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        List<Account> accounts = accountDao.findByEmail(email); 
        Account account = null;
        for (Account possibleAccount : accounts) {
            if (possibleAccount.isEnabled()) {
                 account = possibleAccount;
            }
        }
        if (account == null) {
            Integer accountId = otherService.copyToAccount(email);
            account = accountDao.find(accountId);

            if (account == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(email+ " is not registered.");
            }
        }

        Collection<Role> roles = account.getRoles();

        if (roles.isEmpty()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + email+ " has no authorities");
        }
        return new UserDetailsAdapter(account);
   }
  //...redacted autowiring and logging
}
```

And the wiring:

```
<authentication-manager >
   <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
    <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
   </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService"
         class="com.company.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />

<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>

<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</global-method-security>

<beans:bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator">
        <beans:bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="com.company.web.security.MethodsPermissionEvaluator"/>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

This is Spring 3.2.4.RELEASE.

**Update - To show the object is persisted:**

I am persisting the Company object through a standard CRUD DAO impl:

```
@Override
public Company create() {
   Company company = new Company();
   company.setCreationDate(new Date());
   save(company);
   return company;
}
```

And in the @Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/company"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("company", companyService.createCompany());
    return "company";
}
```

And in the @Service:

```
public Company createCompany() {
     return companyDao.create();
}
```

I see it persisted in the DB with an ID assigned.

Comment: I'm guessing this may happen when you have a newly created object that has not yet been saved (i.e. the id is generated after a save).

Comment: Appreciate the comment, @RobWinch, particularly from a Spring author.   I will take a look.

Comment: I tried saving the object, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our developer was able to correct this by adding the debug information at compile time to our build (in our case, an ant `build.xml`).

For example including "vars" in the debuglevel:

```
  <target name="compile" depends="init"
          description="compile the source">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" source="1.7" target="1.7"
       nowarn="true" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,source,vars"
       includeantruntime="true" deprecation="${deprecation}">
      <compilerarg value="-Xbootclasspath/p:${toString:pathing.classpath}"/>
    </javac>
    <javac srcdir="${project_dir}/src/test" destdir="${build}" source="1.7" target="1.7"
       nowarn="true" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,source,vars"
       includeantruntime="true" deprecation="${deprecation}">
      <compilerarg value="-Xbootclasspath/p:${toString:pathing.classpath}"/>
    </javac>
  </target>
```

Thinking the solution would be similar for a Maven `pom.xml`.

Comment: In the pom.xml it would mean adding to the maven-compiler-plugin: `<debug>true</debug>
 <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>`